# undefined method `create!' for ActiveAdmin Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

ActiveAdmin suddenly started to display this error when I try to create a comment on any model.

```
NoMethodError in Admin::CommentsController#create
undefined method `create!' for #<Admin::CommentsController:0x00007f9a6b2a5640> Did you mean? create
```

I have the latest ActiveAdmin version 2.13.1, ruby 3.2 and rails 6.1

[image]

This error comes from: activeadmin (2.13.1) lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb:66:in `create'

Comment: Using [ActiveAdmin's comment feature](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#comments) or rolling your own?

Comment: It's ActiveAdmin's comment feature, that's why I can't just edit the line where I get the error

Comment: Odd. `create!` is defined in `InheritedResources::Base`, inherited by `ActiveAdmin::BaseController`, `ActiveAdmin::ResourceController` and `Admin::CommentsController`, it is effectively the same as `super`.  Is it specific to this version of ActiveAdmin?  When you say `suddenly`, what changed?

Comment: Sadly I am not sure what changed, it was a feature that was not used too much in the past and users started using it again and reported the error